# Should I store global constants and commonly used static functions inside of the App_Code or elsewhere?

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, constants, organization

I am reorganizing the code in an ASP.NET Webforms application.  I was wondering if it makes more sense to store globally-accessible, commonly-used constants and static functions inside of the App_Code folder or the Classes folder that we have at the same level in the filesystem.

Currently I have the constants and functions stored in static classes within our Classes folder, in the base namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, app_code is "in general" the place to put all that "library" code, and your hodge podge of typical general code routines (that don't need nor warrant being a class).

and as a general rule my helper classes? yes, I also dump (create) them in the app_code.

HOWEVER one big whopper to keep in mind:

Turns out, EVEN using a web application, and EVEN useing a published application?

All your code behind for forms etc. is pre-compiled, including "resolving" that code in app_code.

However, note how I stated "resolving".

The one big issue is that app_code STILL can and will often be compiled by IIS and NOT your publish + compile process!!

In effect, this means that say some code that used the newer Roslyn format?

Well, some types of web hosting's don't allow .exe and the Roslyn bits and parts to be published (or better stated they don't allow .exe and that extra system to be published). But then again, who cares, since you using a publish, and all source code is stripped out and not published, right?

Well, "sort of". As I stated, the ONE exception to this whole process is the app_code folder. it can, and will be attempted to be compiled by IIS. And that often means then your Roslyn code will fail.

And app_code is and WILL be published as raw source code.

so, what I do now?

I moved all of my app_code into a folder called MyCode.

Only extra step is when adding code modules (those static class routines) is to ensure you right click on the code folder, and ensure you set build action as compile.

This one:

[image]

So, me coming from vb land, it was common to have a quite a few routines and subs used in such applications, but they were not classes that required to create a "instance" to use. And thus in c#, then of course the "substitute" for such general module code is of course a static class.

One more FYI:
It is a assumed and all happy and fine as a coding approach to use and have and enjoy that (those) static classes. However, you MUST NOT have public members to that static class that can change per user.

So, I suppose a database connection string could be fine, but ANY context of a public var in that/those static classes can NOT be used, since they are shared among all users hitting the web site.

so, local scoped variables to those methods (functions) in that static class are 100% fine, but NOT ANY variables scoped to all of the static class can be used (if they are to pertain to the one user).

And if you have a existing folder with classes? Then again, that is just fine, and you probably already have noted you need to set the build action to compile - and of course "do not copy", since there is no need nor desire to have such source code published up to the site in question.